# How to make table with multi-tier row header (index) using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data:

```
# colh1 rh1 rh2 rh3/up rh4/down
AddaVax ID LV 29 18
AddaVax ID SP 16 13
AddaVax ID LN 61 73
ADX ID LV 11 14
ADX IP LV 160 88
ADX ID SP 14 13
ADX IP SP 346 129
ADX ID LN 25 25
```

What I'd like to do is to make a table that looks like this
(later to be written in text or Excel file):

[image]

The actual data contain more than 2 columns but the number of rows
is always fixed (i.e. 10 rows).

I'm stuck with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict

dod = defaultdict(dict)
with open("mediate.txt", 'r') as tsvfile:
    tabreader = csv.reader(tsvfile, delimiter=' ')
    for row in tabreader:
        if "#" in row[0]: continue
        colh1, rh1, rh2, rhup, rhdown = row
        dod["colh1"] = colh1
        dod["rh1"] = rh1
        dod["rh2"] = rh2
        dod["rhup"] = rhup
        dod["rhdown"] = rhdown
```

What's the way to do it?

Comment: For starters you can read directly into a dataframe in one line with ```df = pd.read_csv('mediate.txt', sep=' *')``` or something very similar.  After that, you might want to look at http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.2/advanced.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just using Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('mediate.txt', sep='\t')  # or sep=',' if comma delimited.
df.rename(columns={'rh3/up': 'Up', 'rh4/down': 'Down'}, inplace=True)
result = df.pivot_table(values=['Up', 'Down'], 
                        columns='colh1', 
                        index=['rh1', 'rh2']).stack(0)  # Stack Up/Down
>>> result
colh1         ADX  AddaVax
rh1 rh2                   
ID  LN  Up     25       61
        Down   25       73
    LV  Up     11       29
        Down   14       18
    SP  Up     14       16
        Down   13       13
IP  LV  Up    160      NaN
        Down   88      NaN
    SP  Up    346      NaN
        Down  129      NaN
```